# Stop Chrome debugger from showing other scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, javascript-debugger

Using chrome debugger I am often whisked away to different files such as JQuery or Google Ad Manager, which is quite frustrating when I am trying to debug a single file.

If I'm not interested in how these libraries are affecting the script I am trying to debug, is there a way to prevent them from showing up at all? I would think that the `step over` functionality would prevent different scopes from opening, but I suppose that's just for new scopes spawned from the inspected function...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using chrome for debugging you can achieve it by black-boxing the scripts.
Two ways you can do it.

**Using the Settings panel**

- Right-clicking on any script in the Sources panel
- Settings panel

Use the Settings panel to configure blackboxed scripts. Open the DevTools Settings and under Sources click

This will open up a dialog where you can input file names of scripts that you would like to add to the blacklist. You can do this a couple of ways:

- enter the name of a file,
- use regular expressions to target:
- files that contain a specific name /backbone.js$,
- certain types of files like .min.js$ or enter in an entire folder that contains scripts you want to blackbox such as bower_components.

**Context menus**

To use the Settings panel for adding files to the blacklist, you can use the context menu when working in the Sources panel. When viewing a file you can right-click in the editor. And you can right-click on a file in the file navigator. From there choose Blackbox Script. This will add the file to the list in the Settings panel.

**Source:** https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing

Answer (score 0):

I can not find the *blackboxing* mentioned in other replies, probably it no longer exists.

Another thing I have found helpful though, is to ignore the annoying files so they do not show in the next debugging sessions. Here is how to [ignore scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/reference/#editor-ignore-list) from the google developer docs.

Comment: It's the same feature. Blackboxing was renamed to "ignore list"